# remove duplicate lines keep one before

Tags: bash, sh

i want remove duplicate  lines contains "from unit" keep one before like this

input file:

```
 within unit  1
   9. BD (   2) C   3 - C   4        /***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4           14.88    0.25    
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) C   3 - C   4           11.15    0.81 
 from unit  1 to unit  2
   2. BD (   1) C   1 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                    8.16    0.66 
 ***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                  204.76    0.07 
 from unit  1 to unit  3
 from unit  1 to unit  4
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           10.56    1.15    
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           15.67    0.74    
 from unit  1 to unit  5
 from unit  1 to unit  6
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) O  84 - H  85           11.04    1.19    
 from unit  1 to unit  7
 from unit  2 to unit  1
 within unit  2
 from unit  2 to unit  3
 from unit  3 to unit  1
 from unit  3 to unit  2
  40. BD (   2) C  21 - N  22        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                   40.26    0.40
```

output file:

```
 within unit  1
   9. BD (   2) C   3 - C   4        /***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4           14.88    0.25   
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) C   3 - C   4           11.15    0.81  
 from unit  1 to unit  2
   2. BD (   1) C   1 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                    8.16    0.66   
 ***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                  204.76    0.07  
 from unit  1 to unit  4
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           10.56    1.15   
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           15.67    0.74  
 from unit  1 to unit  6
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) O  84 - H  85           11.04    1.19  
 from unit  3 to unit  2
  40. BD (   2) C  21 - N  22        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                   40.26    0.40
```

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A m f

read_matrix() {
    local i=0
    local line
    local j
    # Ignore the first 2 lines containing size of the matrix

    while read -r line; do
        j=0
        # split on spaces
        for v in `echo $line`; do
            m[$i,$j]="$v"
            j=$((j+1))
        done
        i=$((i+1))
    done

 }

 read_matrix      < $1
echo "${1:m[@]}"
a=`awk 'END {print FNR}' $1`

       i=0
       for i in $((a-2)); do
           if [[ m[$i,0] == "from" ]]; then
             if [[ m[$((i+1)),0] != "from" ]]; then
             echo -n  "${m[$i,*]}" >> out.1
             #for ((j=0; j<=5; j++)); do  f[$i,j]=m[$i,j]; done
             #for ((j=0; j<=5; j++)); do unset m[$((i+1)),j]; done
             fi
             else
             for ((j=0; j<=5; j++)); do  f[$i,j]=m[$i,j]; done
             fi
            echo -n  "${f[$i,*]}" >> out.1
            i=$((i+1))
        done
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to ask a question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input, expected output, and code as Code Blocks (I formatted them for you for this question). Make sure to post a [mcve], not just whatever code and data you have lying around.

Comment: Oh, and as the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Once you've fixed the issues that shellcheck will tell you about then [edit] your question to replace your old code with your shellcheck-clean version if you still have a problem you need help with.

Comment: The [tag:sh] and in particular [tag:csh] tags seem misplaced here. Are you seeking a solution which works for all three (which is trivially possible for calling another tool like Awk from any of the three, but basically impossible if you really care about the actual shell script; Csh is syntactically quite different from the Bourne-family shells). Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;/(from|within) unit/{N;s/ *(from|within) unit[^\n]*\n( *(from|within) unit.*)/\2/;ba}' input_file
 within unit  1
   9. BD (   2) C   3 - C   4        /***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4           14.88    0.25
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) C   3 - C   4           11.15    0.81
 from unit  1 to unit  2
   2. BD (   1) C   1 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                    8.16    0.66
 ***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                  204.76    0.07
 from unit  1 to unit  4
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           10.56    1.15
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           15.67    0.74
 from unit  1 to unit  6
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) O  84 - H  85           11.04    1.19
 from unit  3 to unit  2
  40. BD (   2) C  21 - N  22        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                   40.26    0.40
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any `awk` plus `tac`:

```
$ tac file | awk -v tgt='(from|within) unit' '!($0 ~ tgt && prev ~ tgt); {prev=$0}' | tac
 within unit  1
   9. BD (   2) C   3 - C   4        /***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4           14.88    0.25
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) C   3 - C   4           11.15    0.81
 from unit  1 to unit  2
   2. BD (   1) C   1 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                    8.16    0.66
 ***. BD*(   2) C   3 - C   4        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                  204.76    0.07
 from unit  1 to unit  4
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           10.56    1.15
 173. LP (   2) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) N  53 - H  73           15.67    0.74
 from unit  1 to unit  6
 172. LP (   1) O  11                /***. BD*(   1) O  84 - H  85           11.04    1.19
 from unit  3 to unit  2
  40. BD (   2) C  21 - N  22        /171. LP*(   1) H   8                   40.26    0.40
```

Answer (score 1):

Longer awk but only needs one pass:

```
awk '
    $0~re {
        do {
            p0 = $0 RS
            g = getline
        } while ( g==1 && $0~re )
        if (!g) p0 = ""
    }
    {
        print p0 $0
        p0 = ""
    }
' re='(from|within) unit' input
```

- If a line matches the regex:

  - loop saving line and then reading another, until a non-matching line is found (or end of input is reached, or there is an I/O error)
  - if end of input, clear saved line to avoid double-printing
- print current line prefixed by any saved line
- clear any saved line

---

Similar idea for a sed with ERE support (needed for alternation):

```
sed -n -E '
    /(from|within) unit/ {
:a
        h       # save current line
        n       # read next line
        // ba   # loop if still matches (reuses regex above)

        x
        p       # print saved line
        x       
    }
    p           # print current line
' input
```

This truncates input if final line matches (`n` at EOF makes sed exit so `p` never happens)